# Possible values of a determinant whose entries are $-1$, $0$ and $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be a $3\times3$ matrix whose entries in the first column are all equal to $1$. If the other entries are $-1$, $0$ or $1$, then find how many distinct values can $\det A$ take.

I want to know how this can be solved in a clever way. I found a brute force way to do it: we can subtract the first row from the second and the third, thus getting a $2\times 2$ determinant. We may now solve the problem with enough patience, but I don't think that this is the best way to tackle the problem since it was asked in a contest and due to the time limit my approach would be rendered useless.

Comment: "Develop" the determinant with respect to the first column. You will get sum of 3 terms, each equal to $-1,0, 1$. So, any integer from $-3$ to $3$.

Comment: @Salcio Not really, one of the terms may also be $\begin{vmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ -1 &-1\end{vmatrix}$, which equals $2$.

Comment: @Salcio Your reasoning combined with mine tells us that the determinant may be any integer from $-4$ to $4$. This would tell us that $\det A$ may take $9$ distinct values, but how do we easily show that each of these is actually attained?

Comment: @TheZone use Laplace expansion along the first column. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion

Comment: Good point, so the sum of 3 elements each can be -2,-1,0,1, or 2. I was not attempting to solve this. It can be tedious to check if each case is legit.

Comment: @Salcio Yeah, I agree, that was the part that didn't work with my approach too (I also ended up with having to check if all those values can be attained), but I think/hope that there is some clever way to go about it.

Comment: @CyclotomicField this is precisely what Salcio proposed

Comment: This may help - one can add/subtract column to other column without changing determinant. So, one can assume that the first row has this form: 1, 0, 0. In particular, determinant reduces to 2 x 2 matrix with entries from -2 to 2.

Comment: Related: https://oeis.org/A003433; it is also the sequence of maximal determinants of $n \times n$ $(-1,0,1)$-matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you consider "brute force", but here's how I would do it:

We know that
$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & a & b\\1 & c & d\\ 1 & e & f\end{bmatrix}$

and $\det(A) =  ad + cf + eb - (af + cb + ed)$

Each of those terms is $-1, 0,$ or $ 1$.

Also, the first 3 cannot be 1 with the last 3 all being -1, since that would require the number of -1 entries to be both odd and even. Nor could one of the first 3 terms be 0 without one of the last 3 terms being 0.

Therefore, $|\det(A)|\le4$.

Now, it is easy to find an $A$ which has determinant zero. Also, for any $A$, we can switch the sign of the determinant by swapping the last two columns.

So it remains to be shown that we can find $A$ with determinants 1, 2, 3 and 4.

The first two seem rather easy:

$\left| \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\1 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\right| = 1$

$\left| \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\1 & 1 & -1\\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\right| = 2$

Since the bottom two entries of the first two columns are the same, we see that

$\left| \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & 0\\1 & 1 & -1\\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\right| = 4$

To make a determinant of 3, we need one of the 2x2 submatrices to have determinant 2, and the other to have determinant 1, which suggests adding a zero:

$\left| \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & 0\\1 & 1 & -1\\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\right| = 3$

So there are nine possible values of the determinant.

Comment: by brute force I meant not being clever and excluding some cases. It was also pretty dumb of me not to notice that we only need to find $A$'s for half of the values since we can swap rows. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. These problems are tricky, and it took me a while of thinking about it to figure out how to exclude cases. I doubt I would do well with a time limit.